# VBA returning only "one sheet name" into listbox with userform initializing though many more sheets are expected

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

 'declare the variable

 Dim Sh As Variant

 Dim cc As Variant

 cc = Sheet4.Range("C4").Value

 'for each loop to add sheets based on permission rank

 For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

    'add only permitted sheet(ranking 1 to 6) and exclude settings sheet
    If Sh.Range("G1").Value >= cc And Sh.Name <> "settings" Then
    'add sheets to the list box
        Me.lstSheet.AddItem Sh.Name
    End If

Next Sh

End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps `ActiveWorkbook` should be `ThisWorkbook`?

Comment: Difficult for us to suggest a fix without knowing the cell values in question. Code looks fine to me...

Comment: the cell value ranges from 1 to 6

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Me.Repaint after Me.1stSheet.AddItem

This will refresh the Form.

Consider changing your ListBox variable name from 1stSheet to sheet1ListBox too, to make it more descriptive and easier to debug.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The problem was, I had numbers in the cc range and after formatting the cell value as number the issue has resolved, nothing with the code.